# how to use form builder to make form from entity relation of entity in symfony4

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

TL;TR:How to make form fields from formbuilder with relation column

Here is my **Level Entity**

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\LevelRepository")
 */
class Level
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=10)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Area", mappedBy="levelid", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $areas;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->areas = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDescription(): ?string
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function setDescription(?string $description): self
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Area[]
     */
    public function getAreas(): Collection
    {
        return $this->areas;
    }

    public function addArea(Area $area): self
    {
        if (!$this->areas->contains($area)) {
            $this->areas[] = $area;
            $area->setLevelid($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeArea(Area $area): self
    {
        if ($this->areas->contains($area)) {
            $this->areas->removeElement($area);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($area->getLevelid() === $this) {
                $area->setLevelid(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

and this is my **Area Entity**

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\AreaRepository")
 */
class Area
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Property", mappedBy="area")
     */
    private $property;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Level", inversedBy="areas")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $levelid;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->property = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->projects = new ArrayCollection();

    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|property[]
     */
    public function getProperty(): Collection
    {
        return $this->property;
    }

    public function addProperty(property $property): self
    {
        if (!$this->property->contains($property)) {
            $this->property[] = $property;
            $property->setArea($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeProperty(property $property): self
    {
        if ($this->property->contains($property)) {
            $this->property->removeElement($property);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($property->getArea() === $this) {
                $property->setArea(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLevelid(): ?Level
    {
        return $this->levelid;
    }

    public function setLevelid(?Level $levelid): self
    {
        $this->levelid = $levelid;

        return $this;
    }

   }
```

Area connected to Level

And this is `Area Form builder`

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Area;
// use App\Entity\District;
use App\Entity\Level;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;

class AreaType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('Level', EntityType::class, array(
                // looks for choices from this entity
                'class' => Level::class,
                'label' => 'Level',
                // uses the User.username property as the visible option string
                'choice_label' => 'name',
            ))
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Area::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

And the error is

> Neither the property "Level" nor one of the methods "getLevel()", "level()", "isLevel()", "hasLevel()", "__get()" exist and have public access in class "App\Entity\Area".

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is caused by form field and Entity field name mismatch. `AreaType` tries to refer to `level` property using Symfony's `PropertyAccessor` on `Area` while it does not have such field.

You should either rename your entity field from `$levelid` to `$level` (because it actually holds an Entity, not ID), changing setter and getter accordingly (recommended solution) or change form field name from `Level` to `levelid`.

You can find more information about Symfony Forms in [official docummentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html).